# How to install `vega.js` and `vega editor` for running vega examples locally?

Tags: vega

I have tried to install vega.js and vega editor locally using [recommended method 1](https://github.com/vega/vega) with npm, but my Mac never finish running `npm install`.

I also tried the 3rd method: `npm install vega`, this time I managed to install the vega.js as a node module, see the image below. However, I have no idea how to run vega examples using this node project and vega modules. 
[image]

When I tried to install vega editor as I run `npm run vendor`, I got the following errors:

```
They are for You: /Users/Natsume/Documents/D3_dc/3. node_npm_vega
 ->npm run vendor
npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "vendor"
npm ERR! node v4.4.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
npm ERR! path /Users/Natsume/Documents/D3_dc/3. node_npm_vega/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Natsume/Documents/D3_dc/3. node_npm_vega/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Natsume/Documents/D3_dc/3. node_npm_vega/npm-debug.log
They are for You: /Users/Natsume/Documents/D3_dc/3. node_npm_vega
```

It seems suggest that there should be a `package.json`, but where should I get it? Should I continue to look for answers on how to install vega and vega editor using npm?

If possible, could anyone show me how to run vega examples with vega editor locally without using `npm install`? Thanks!

Comment: Why it is preferred to install and even run vega projects using node and npm?

Answer (score 0):

I have just worked out a way to run a few vega examples locally without using npm.

It turned out that it is achieved by [reading this page](https://github.com/vega/vega/wiki/Runtime).

1. cope and paste code from **Basic Use** to make your own index.html
2. copy and paste vega examples folder into your own working directory
3. copy and paste vega dataset into your working directory
4. then choose the example.json file and fill into your index.html and run

However, this solution still cannot let me use vega editor locally. Vega editor's debugger looks fantastic.